# Scala way to create custom permissions

Tags: scala, oop, functional-programming

I have an app that allows users to reserve rooms.  I want to add the ability for users to assign various permissions to each room

eg User is an Operator AND is assigned to this building OR is admin.

the list of conditions (isOperator etc) will be defined by me but how they are combined will be up to the user.  The order the conditions are applied matters I think. So I am thinking three db tables, one for the conditions, one for the combinators(&, or etc) and one for each user created combination that will probably have a pivot table with conditions that also stores the order and the next combinator to be used

My question is what is the scala, mix of oop and functional,  way of doing this.  I want to call a function with say the room and the user and get a boolean back.

That function should get each condition and combinator in the correct order, preferably somehow know how to replace each combinator with the standard scala language &, or, etc, check each condition against the user and the room and return the boolean

Comment: This is a design question and the answer to your question is that it depends. It depends on how much functional programming theory you know and how that theory applies to Scala. Do you know what HOFs are?

Comment: I would say I am a novice at both but have an understanding of both at least to the extent that I was able to complete Oderskys functional programming with scala coursera course and yes if you mean higher order functions I understand what they are

Comment: In Scala, we model nouns in the domain just like we would do in Java. For example, a Reservation, a User, a BusinessRule, a Room. Within those classes you will have function definitions which model the required behaviour. In order to code in a functional way those functions must not have any side-effects. I would place your function you describe above in the Reservation class as it is describes behaviour associated with that class. In terms of how to model the data and define the functions, well, there are many ways to do that; have a look at the collections library.

Answer (score 1):

I've been exploring the same recently. We will probably use Apache Shiro in the authorization layer, but I did some exploring to find some existing work that takes a functional approach to authorization. I didn't have much luck other than some Haskell examples. Even that used a role-based solution that I wasn't happy with. For example, I don't want to validate that a user has admin role, I want to validate that the user has permission to do some action. I want roles only to compose permissions, and assign them to users. Hopefully someone has a suggestion. Maybe this is fertile ground for a new project.